# Spring Security simulataneous usage of multiple PasswordEncoders

Tags: encoding, spring-security, passwords, bcrypt, sha

I have spring app with simple configuration of Spring Security using bcrypt (default parameters)  and the test works fine, however i want to plan that this application gives the  ability to the administrator or the user to change password and select authentication parameters to be used such as: 
1)bcrypt (BCryptPasswordEncoder)
2)hash function such as sha (StandardPasswordEncoder),

So the question is how to change the following class (or the AuthenticationManagerBuilder specifically ) in order to reflect that some users could have they password stored as a sha hash but other as bcrypt, Taking into account that the database table already have a column that specify what kind of hash is being stored in the password column i.e. bcrypt or sha.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled=true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService iUserDetailsService;


    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http
//          .csrf().disable()
//          .headers().disable()
            .headers()
            .contentTypeOptions()
            .xssProtection()
            .cacheControl()
            .httpStrictTransportSecurity()
            .frameOptions()
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-Content-Security-Policy","script-src 'self"))
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("Content-Security-Policy","script-src 'self'"))
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-WebKit-CSP","default-src 'self'"))
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .accessDeniedHandler(syncAccessDeniedHandler())
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(   "/register",
                                "/static/**",
                                "/h2/**",
                                "/resources/**",
                                "/static/css/**", 
                                "/static/img/**" , 
                                "/static/js/**", 
                                "/static/pdf/**",
                                "/resources/static/css/**", 
                                "/resources/static/img/**" , 
                                "/resources/static/js/**", 
                                "/resources/static/pdf/**",
                                "/pdf/**",
                                "/css/**",
                                "/js/**",
                                "/img/**"

                                ).permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/admin/dashboard/**").hasAnyRole("STUDENT", "ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/admin/network/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .permitAll();
    }



    @Autowired
    public void registerAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .userDetailsService(iUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(pwEncoder());        
    }

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder pwEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();        
    }


    @Bean
    public SyncAccessDeniedHandler syncAccessDeniedHandler() {
        String uri = "/403";
        return new SyncAccessDeniedHandler(uri);
    }



}
```

Comment: Why do you want to use SHA rather bcrypt for any accounts? Also, you can tell them apart from the format of the string (bcrypt is pretty distinctive), rather than needing a separate DB column. So you can just implement a `PasswordEncoder` which looks at the string and then delegates to the appropriate encoder.

Comment: The reason why i really asked this question is because i what to plan to be able to use scrypt in the future  (http://www.tarsnap.com/scrypt.html). So when you mentioned to implement PasswordEncoder that looks in the string and then depending on the string uses the right encoder. Do you know if there are any examples out there?

Comment: Using scrypt is another matter altogether as it doesn't have a standard string format. You would have to encode the parameters yourself in the string. However, it should still be possible to differentiate from a bcrypt string or a plain hex-encoded string.

Comment: As i mentioned the database already have additional column that says what kind of hash is being stored there i.e. bcrypt, scrypt, md5 and if pbkdf2 is used on the hash then i have a column saying how many round of PBKDF2 has been made.So there is not problem with differentiating between different hashes i am just looking for example implementation  i.e. how it should be done the right way in Spring Security as i have never done it before. I am pretty new to Spring Security.

Comment: Were you able to do it? I need to do exactly same thing. I have a column in db for encryption type and then user level encryption should be there. Can you please post your answer if done?

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use  DelegatingPasswordEncoder from spring 5.0 or extend it to create your own version.

https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/api/org/springframework/security/crypto/password/DelegatingPasswordEncoder.html